# How to make different directory project found in current project include directory via CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following directory structure of a CMake based project:

[image: /home/project/submodule1/]

I am trying to `#include "driver.h"` in `iconsumer.hpp`.But during compilation, I am getting an error that `driver.h` file not found in `iconsumer.hpp`.

Following is the content of project/consumer/include/src/CMakeLists.txt
prject(MyConsumer CXX)

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED consumer.cpp)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} DriverHeaders)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wno-attributes)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Following is the content of project/driver/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCE driver.cpp)
add_library(DriverHeaders OBJECT ${SOURCE})
set_property(TARGET DriverHeaders PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

How to make `driver.h` visible and includable in `iconsumer.hpp`?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html Btw: This is not a good idea `install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` It basically prevents you from creating a package, that is unless you want the package to be installed in the exact absolute path where your project recides. Usually you don't want to impose such a restriction on the location of your sources and require someone who wants the built project to be installed locally to set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and specify paths relative to this dir for `install` destinations.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/driver)` work?